# Threading decorator is passed two args when decorating method of pyqt5 application object

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, decorator

I am trying to define a decorator which threads the execution of some of the callback functions for the buttons in a PyQt5 GUI application. I have defined the decorator as follows:

```
def threaded(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        th = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        th.start()
        return th
    return wrapper
```

And the application code is:

```
class Application(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.setupUi(window)
        self.connect_slots()

    def connect_slots(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.push_button_pressed)

    @threaded
    def push_button_pressed(self):
        print("Pressed!")
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = QMainWindow()
    window = Application(main_window)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

for reference, the Ui_MainWindow class is defined in a separate file (generated from qtdesigner and pyuic5).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(115, 101)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 115, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

The problem that I am running into is the following Traceback when the button is pressed.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: push_button_pressed() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The `*args` is being passed two arguments for some reason, `(<__main__.Application object at 0x0000000002E8FDA0>, False)`
As you can see, the first is the instance of the class as expected, but the second is some boolean value. Where is that argument coming from? When I try this decorator on a simple python class (without pyqt) only the instance is passed as I expect.

If I add the wildcard args to the application method everything will execute alright (`def push_button_pressed(self, *args, **kwargs):`), but that seems more like a workaround than an actual solution.

What is that boolean argument and is this even a valid approach?

Comment: You can simply consult the [docs for the clicked signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) for an explanation of its parameters. The other question is impossible to answer, since you don't fully explain what you expect the code to do or what problem you are trying to solve by using it.

Comment: So I see in the docs that the signal is returning a `checked` boolean indicating the checked state of the button, but why is that passed to the function when decorated? If I remove the decorator, there is no `TypeError` thrown, as if it only gets passed the class instance in that case.

Comment: If you read the traceback, you will see that your wrapper indescriminately passes ***all*** arguments to `func` (aka `self._target`). But `push_button_pressed` (aka `func`) clearly does not have any arguments (other than `self`). So don't do that.

Comment: PS: I don't know what you intent to do with this decorator, but it does not look thread-safe. Qt does not support gui operations of any kind outside the main thread, so passing `self` to a worker thread seems dubious.